# Printing to an interactive terminal inside a docker container from outside

Tags: python, docker

I am running a Docker container with

```
docker run --name client_container -v ~/client/vol:/vol --network host -it --entrypoint '/bin/bash' --privileged client_image:latest -c "bash /execute/start_client.sh && /bin/bash"
```

I have a service on the host machine and I would like it to be able to print something to the interactive bash terminal at an arbitrary time.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do this.

In general it's difficult at best to write things to other terminal windows; Docker adding an additional layer of isolation makes this pretty much impossible.  The `docker run -t` option means there probably is a special device file inside the container that could reach that terminal session, but since the host and container filesystems are isolated from each other, a host process can't access it at all.

Comment: and it's not possible to run a background process in the container listening on a socket for example?

Comment: Usually you'd have the _foreground_ process in the container listening for network connections.  Technically anything you can launch from a shell script or another process will run, but general practice is to avoid background processes.